Is it possible to insert a slicer before the vba code runs?
I have created a vba code which copies data from the main sheet to a new sheet depending on a specific cell "Status". If Status is set to active then that particular row is copied and pasted to a new sheet called active. If the status is changed to inactive then that specific row copies and pastes to a new worksheet called inactive.
I have not yet found a way to remove the row from the copied sheet if the status is changed to something else on the main sheet.
My main issue is that I would like to insert a slicer which allows the user to choose the province of the member first.
Once the province is selected, I then need the row to be copied to the new worksheet once the user changes the members status.
I created the vba code which has worked but its really slow.
I then inserted a slicer but now it is not working properly
The code is below:
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 Dim lngLastRow As Long
 Dim ActiveSheet As Worksheet, InactiveSheet As Worksheet, PendingSheet As Worksheet, RenewedSheet As Worksheet, FollowUpSheet As Worksheet, RedZoneSheet As Worksheet

 Set ActiveSheet = Sheets("Active")
 Set InactiveSheet = Sheets("Inactive")
 Set PendingSheet = Sheets("Pending")
 Set RenewedSheet = Sheets("Renewed")
 Set FollowUpSheet = Sheets("Follow Up")
 Set RedZoneSheet = Sheets("Red Zone")

 lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

 With Range("A5", "R" & lngLastRow)
 .AutoFilter
 .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Active"
 .Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
 .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Inactive"
 .Copy InactiveSheet.Range("A1")
 .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Pending"
 .Copy PendingSheet.Range("A1")
 .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Renewed"
 .Copy RenewedSheet.Range("A1")
 .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Follow Up"
 .Copy FollowUpSheet.Range("A1")
 .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Red Zone"
 .Copy RedZoneSheet.Range("A1")
 .AutoFilter
 End With

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

 End Sub


I suggest to change the ActiveSheet name since it's already used by the application to identify, you know, the active sheet. Anyway, try using arrays. Here an example:
Option Explicit
 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim ActiveSheet As Worksheet, InactiveSheet As Worksheet, PendingSheet As Worksheet, RenewedSheet As Worksheet, FollowUpSheet As Worksheet, RedZoneSheet As Worksheet
    Dim VarSource() As Variant, VarActive() As Variant, VarInactive() As Variant, VarPending() As Variant, VarRenewed() As Variant, VarFollowUp() As Variant, VarRedzone() As Variant
    Dim DblRowIndex As Double, DblColumnIndex As Double, DblCriteriaColumn As Double, DblActiveIndex As Double, DblInactiveIndex As Double, DblPendingIndex As Double, DblRenewedIndex As Double, DblFollowUpIndex As Double, DblRedzoneIndex As Double
    
    Set ActiveSheet = Sheets("Active")
    Set InactiveSheet = Sheets("Inactive")
    Set PendingSheet = Sheets("Pending")
    Set RenewedSheet = Sheets("Renewed")
    Set FollowUpSheet = Sheets("Follow Up")
    Set RedZoneSheet = Sheets("Red Zone")
    
    DblCriteriaColumn = 4
    
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    VarSource = Range("A5", "R" & lngLastRow).Value2
    
    ReDim VarActive(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
    ReDim VarInactive(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
    ReDim VarPending(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
    ReDim VarRenewed(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
    ReDim VarFollowUp(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
    ReDim VarRedzone(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
    
    DblRowIndex = 1
    
    For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
        
        VarActive(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
        VarInactive(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
        VarPending(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
        VarRenewed(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
        VarFollowUp(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
        VarRedzone(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
        
    Next
    
    DblActiveIndex = 1
    DblInactiveIndex = 1
    DblPendingIndex = 1
    DblRenewedIndex = 1
    DblFollowUpIndex = 1
    DblRedzoneIndex = 1
    
    For DblRowIndex = 2 To UBound(VarSource, 1)
        
        Select Case VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblCriteriaColumn)
            Case Is = "Active"
                
                DblActiveIndex = DblActiveIndex + 1
                
                For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                    
                    VarActive(DblActiveIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                    
                Next
                
            Case Is = "Inactive"
                
                DblInactiveIndex = DblInactiveIndex + 1
                
                For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                    
                    VarInactive(DblInactiveIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                    
                Next
                
            Case Is = "Pending"
                
                DblPendingIndex = DblPendingIndex + 1
                
                For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                    
                    VarPending(DblPendingIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                    
                Next
                
            Case Is = "Renewed"
                
                DblRenewedIndex = DblRenewedIndex + 1
                
                For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                    
                    VarRenewed(DblRenewedIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                    
                Next
                
            Case Is = "Follow Up"
                
                DblFollowUpIndex = DblFollowUpIndex + 1
                
                For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                    
                    VarFollowUp(DblFollowUpIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                    
                Next
                
            Case Is = "Red Zone"
                
                DblRedzoneIndex = DblRedzoneIndex + 1
                
                For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                    
                    VarRedzone(DblRedzoneIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                    
                Next
                
        End Select
        
        
    Next
    
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarActive, 1), UBound(VarActive, 2)).Value2 = VarActive
    InactiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarInactive, 1), UBound(VarInactive, 2)).Value2 = VarInactive
    PendingSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarPending, 1), UBound(VarPending, 2)).Value2 = VarPending
    RenewedSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarRenewed, 1), UBound(VarRenewed, 2)).Value2 = VarRenewed
    FollowUpSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarFollowUp, 1), UBound(VarFollowUp, 2)).Value2 = VarFollowUp
    RedZoneSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarRedzone, 1), UBound(VarRedzone, 2)).Value2 = VarRedzone
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
End Sub

It might be also wise to run the subroutine only when the proper column is changed. To achieve this, you might nest the previous code in an If statement like this:
Option Explicit
 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim RngCriteria As Range
    
    Set RngCriteria = Range("D:D")
    
    If Intersect(RngCriteria, Target) Is Nothing Then
        
    Else
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        
        Dim lngLastRow As Long
        Dim ActiveSheet As Worksheet, InactiveSheet As Worksheet, PendingSheet As Worksheet, RenewedSheet As Worksheet, FollowUpSheet As Worksheet, RedZoneSheet As Worksheet
        Dim VarSource() As Variant, VarActive() As Variant, VarInactive() As Variant, VarPending() As Variant, VarRenewed() As Variant, VarFollowUp() As Variant, VarRedzone() As Variant
        Dim DblRowIndex As Double, DblColumnIndex As Double, DblCriteriaColumn As Double, DblActiveIndex As Double, DblInactiveIndex As Double, DblPendingIndex As Double, DblRenewedIndex As Double, DblFollowUpIndex As Double, DblRedzoneIndex As Double
        
        Set ActiveSheet = Sheets("Active")
        Set InactiveSheet = Sheets("Inactive")
        Set PendingSheet = Sheets("Pending")
        Set RenewedSheet = Sheets("Renewed")
        Set FollowUpSheet = Sheets("Follow Up")
        Set RedZoneSheet = Sheets("Red Zone")
        
        DblCriteriaColumn = 4
        
        lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        VarSource = Range("A5", "R" & lngLastRow).Value2
        
        ReDim VarActive(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
        ReDim VarInactive(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
        ReDim VarPending(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
        ReDim VarRenewed(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
        ReDim VarFollowUp(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
        ReDim VarRedzone(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
        
        DblRowIndex = 1
        
        For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
            
            VarActive(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
            VarInactive(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
            VarPending(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
            VarRenewed(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
            VarFollowUp(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
            VarRedzone(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
            
        Next
        
        DblActiveIndex = 1
        DblInactiveIndex = 1
        DblPendingIndex = 1
        DblRenewedIndex = 1
        DblFollowUpIndex = 1
        DblRedzoneIndex = 1
        
        For DblRowIndex = 2 To UBound(VarSource, 1)
            
            Select Case VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblCriteriaColumn)
                Case Is = "Active"
                    
                    DblActiveIndex = DblActiveIndex + 1
                    
                    For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                        
                        VarActive(DblActiveIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                        
                    Next
                    
                Case Is = "Inactive"
                    
                    DblInactiveIndex = DblInactiveIndex + 1
                    
                    For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                        
                        VarInactive(DblInactiveIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                        
                    Next
                    
                Case Is = "Pending"
                    
                    DblPendingIndex = DblPendingIndex + 1
                    
                    For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                        
                        VarPending(DblPendingIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                        
                    Next
                    
                Case Is = "Renewed"
                    
                    DblRenewedIndex = DblRenewedIndex + 1
                    
                    For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                        
                        VarRenewed(DblRenewedIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                        
                    Next
                    
                Case Is = "Follow Up"
                    
                    DblFollowUpIndex = DblFollowUpIndex + 1
                    
                    For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                        
                        VarFollowUp(DblFollowUpIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                        
                    Next
                    
                Case Is = "Red Zone"
                    
                    DblRedzoneIndex = DblRedzoneIndex + 1
                    
                    For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                        
                        VarRedzone(DblRedzoneIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                        
                    Next
                    
            End Select
            
            
        Next
        
        
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarActive, 1), UBound(VarActive, 2)).Value2 = VarActive
        InactiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarInactive, 1), UBound(VarInactive, 2)).Value2 = VarInactive
        PendingSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarPending, 1), UBound(VarPending, 2)).Value2 = VarPending
        RenewedSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarRenewed, 1), UBound(VarRenewed, 2)).Value2 = VarRenewed
        FollowUpSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarFollowUp, 1), UBound(VarFollowUp, 2)).Value2 = VarFollowUp
        RedZoneSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarRedzone, 1), UBound(VarRedzone, 2)).Value2 = VarRedzone
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        
    End If
    
End Sub


I have tried the code and can confirm it works perfectly.
In order to use a slicer to filter data and then copy information based on the dropdown list to a new worksheet, use the following code.
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim RngCriteria As Range

Set RngCriteria = Range("D:D")

If Intersect(RngCriteria, Target) Is Nothing Then
    
Else
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim ActiveSheet As Worksheet, InactiveSheet As Worksheet, PendingSheet As Worksheet, RenewedSheet As Worksheet, FollowUpSheet As Worksheet, RedZoneSheet As Worksheet
    Dim VarSource() As Variant, VarActive() As Variant, VarInactive() As Variant, VarPending() As Variant, VarRenewed() As Variant, VarFollowUp() As Variant, VarRedzone() As Variant
    Dim DblRowIndex As Double, DblColumnIndex As Double, DblCriteriaColumn As Double, DblActiveIndex As Double, DblInactiveIndex As Double, DblPendingIndex As Double, DblRenewedIndex As Double, DblFollowUpIndex As Double, DblRedzoneIndex As Double
    
    Set ActiveSheet = Sheets("Active")
    Set InactiveSheet = Sheets("Inactive")
    Set PendingSheet = Sheets("Pending")
    Set RenewedSheet = Sheets("Renewed")
    Set FollowUpSheet = Sheets("Follow Up")
    Set RedZoneSheet = Sheets("Red Zone")
    
    DblCriteriaColumn = 4
    
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    VarSource = Range("A5", "R" & lngLastRow).Value2
    
    ReDim VarActive(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
    ReDim VarInactive(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
    ReDim VarPending(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
    ReDim VarRenewed(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
    ReDim VarFollowUp(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
    ReDim VarRedzone(1 To UBound(VarSource, 1), 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2))
    
    DblRowIndex = 1
    
    For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
        
        VarActive(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
        VarInactive(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
        VarPending(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
        VarRenewed(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
        VarFollowUp(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
        VarRedzone(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
        
    Next
    
    DblActiveIndex = 1
    DblInactiveIndex = 1
    DblPendingIndex = 1
    DblRenewedIndex = 1
    DblFollowUpIndex = 1
    DblRedzoneIndex = 1
    
    For DblRowIndex = 2 To UBound(VarSource, 1)
        
        Select Case VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblCriteriaColumn)
            Case Is = "Active"
                
                DblActiveIndex = DblActiveIndex + 1
                
                For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                    
                    VarActive(DblActiveIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                    
                Next
                
            Case Is = "Inactive"
                
                DblInactiveIndex = DblInactiveIndex + 1
                
                For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                    
                    VarInactive(DblInactiveIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                    
                Next
                
            Case Is = "Pending"
                
                DblPendingIndex = DblPendingIndex + 1
                
                For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                    
                    VarPending(DblPendingIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                    
                Next
                
            Case Is = "Renewed"
                
                DblRenewedIndex = DblRenewedIndex + 1
                
                For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                    
                    VarRenewed(DblRenewedIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                    
                Next
                
            Case Is = "Follow Up"
                
                DblFollowUpIndex = DblFollowUpIndex + 1
                
                For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                    
                    VarFollowUp(DblFollowUpIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                    
                Next
                
            Case Is = "Red Zone"
                
                DblRedzoneIndex = DblRedzoneIndex + 1
                
                For DblColumnIndex = 1 To UBound(VarSource, 2)
                    
                    VarRedzone(DblRedzoneIndex, DblColumnIndex) = VarSource(DblRowIndex, DblColumnIndex)
                    
                Next
                
        End Select
        
        
    Next
    
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarActive, 1), UBound(VarActive, 2)).Value2 = VarActive
    InactiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarInactive, 1), UBound(VarInactive, 2)).Value2 = VarInactive
    PendingSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarPending, 1), UBound(VarPending, 2)).Value2 = VarPending
    RenewedSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarRenewed, 1), UBound(VarRenewed, 2)).Value2 = VarRenewed
    FollowUpSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarFollowUp, 1), UBound(VarFollowUp, 2)).Value2 = VarFollowUp
    RedZoneSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarRedzone, 1), UBound(VarRedzone, 2)).Value2 = VarRedzone
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
End If

End Sub
